# Create MipMap image manually (iOS OpenGL)

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Currently I'm loading a texture with this code :

```
GLKTextureInfo * t = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:@{GLKTextureLoaderGenerateMipmaps: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]} error:&error];
```

But the result is not that good when I scaled down the image (jagged edged).

Can I create my own mipmap using image software like Adobe Illustrator? But what is the rule to do that?
And how do I load this image using the code ?

Thanks!

-- Edited --

Thanks for the answer, I got it using :

```
GLuint texName;
glGenTextures(1, &texName);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

// load image data here
...

// set up mipmap
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData0);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_RGBA, 128,128, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData1);
...
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 8, GL_RGBA, 1, 1, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData8);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can manually make the mipmaps and upload them yourself. If you're using Illustrator, presumably it has some method to output an image at a particular resolution. I'm not that familiar with Illustrator, so I don't know how that part works.

Once you have the various resolutions, you can upload them as part of your main image. You can use `glTexImage2D()` to upload the original image to a texture. Then you can upload additional mipmap levels using `glTexImage2D()`, but setting the level parameter to other values. For example:

```
glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, level, etc...);
```

where `level` is the mipmap level for this particular image. Note that you will probably have to set the various texture parameters appropriately for mipmaps, such as:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, <whatever the max is here>);
```

See the [section on mipmaps on this page](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes) for details.